# NavBar Menu Responsive

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, css-transforms, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to  made a **burger menu** with *CSS/JS.*

I have a **navbar (nav)** menu that display like this in *computers:*

[image]

And in **Burger Menu** when the resolution is **less than 768 px** (resolutions for tablet and devices that is under this resolution) like this:

[image]

The **burger menu button is hidden (with display:none) when we are in computers**, but I make it appear when the resolution is (>768px), and it shown, and with Javascript I grab this button and add event Listener to it.

When we click on the burger button, a list menu ( element) **have to appear form the right to left with translateX(0%**), because I **made the list initially transform:translateX(-100%) to go out of the screen** (I *add to body an overflow-x:hidden to hide the excess* and to provide a horizontal scrollbar, anyway)..

The style for the ***ul.nav_links initially***:

```
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                top: 8vh;
                height: 92vh;
                background-color: rgb(68, 122, 122);
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                width: 50%;
                transition: transform 2s;
                transform: translateX(100%);
```

The **class I want to add** (just to return to 0%):

```
// Class to add in JavaScript
.nav_active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

The ***Js code***:

```
//grabbing the burger button
let burger=document.querySelector(".burger");
//grabbing the ul element with class (nav_links)
let nav=document.querySelector(".nav_links");

//Add the listener to burger button, that have to toggle the class "nav_active"
burger.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    nav.classList.toggle("nav_active");
})
```

But for some reason the class (named:nav_active), is adding correctly to the  (I *use the devtools* of Chrome and the class toggle each time I click on it, ***i can see the class add and remove to***), **but the transform:translateX(0%), it doesn't works.**

[image]

I don't know why ?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of this so that I can solve it because I need to see more of your code

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but can you try this?

```
.nav_active {
    transform: translateX(0%) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is CSS specificity; the class for `ul.nav_links` will take higher priority than just a `.nav_active` class.

The order of cascade is as follows: (copied from w3schools link below)

1. Inline styles - An inline style is attached directly to the element to be styled. Example: `<h1 style="color: #ffffff;">`.
2. IDs - An ID is a unique identifier for the page elements, such as #navbar.
3. Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes - This category includes .classes, [attributes] and pseudo-classes such as :hover, :focus etc.
4. Elements and pseudo-elements - This category includes element names and pseudo-elements, such as h1, div, :before and :after.

So the `.nav_active` is being overwritten by the class of higher specificity, meaning element + class in this example. If they were the same level of specificity, (`ul.nav_links` and `ul.nav_active`, for example), then the one that is defined LATER is the one that takes preference.

You would likely find that changing the `.nav_active` class to `ul.nav_active` or even `ul.nav_links.nav_active` would be enough to make the active class apply correctly.

See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp for some details on how to better understand / calculate the specificity level.

Comment: I can't specify ul.nav_active with classList.add() method, because the ul is the name of the element and not a class name, and the method classList add accept just a class name not a tag name ... :/ ??

Comment: Where you define the class in your CSS is where you'd make the change

Comment: Using classList will modify the classes on the element, but the CSS isn't changing, just the assigned class to a given element

Comment: I suggest you read the CSS specificity link